# Doctrine findBy with multiple conditional fields

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have some bad data in the table but not all fields have null values and I want to get all bad rows with one iteration by implementing something like this, if possible.

```
$contactObj = $this->em->getRepository("ImporterBundle:Contact")
->findBy([$field1 => null OR $field2 => null OR $field3 => null ...]);
```

Are there is a solution to do something like above example without using **repositoryClass**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I just need to use repository class

And use expressions.

```
public function getBadData() {
    $db = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');

    return $db->select('c')
        ->where($db->expr()->isNull('c.functions'))
        ->orWhere($db->expr()->isNull('c.salutation'))
        ->orWhere($db->expr()->isNull('c.category'))
        ->orWhere($db->expr()->isNull('c.address'))
        ->orWhere($db->expr()->isNull('c.city'))
        ->orWhere($db->expr()->isNull('c.company'))
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

As JimL suggested, I had change repository method by using **`orX()`**

```
public function getBadData() {
    $db = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');

    return $db->select('c')
        ->where($db->expr()->orX()->addMultiple(
            [
                'c.functions is null',
                'c.salutation is null',
                'c.category is null',
                'c.address is null',
                'c.city is null',
                'c.company is null'
            ]
        ))
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Which now should be more readable.

Comment: You actually don't have to add the select, the createQueryBuilder method automatically selects the entity belonging to the repository for you. You can also use querybuilder expressions andX/orX to avoid repeating andWhere/orWhere so many times. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f5d39d0cd9c155a7c6a7185d8abc7f1e7a9dabef

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **matching(Criteria $criteria)** function of **Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository**:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

$criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->where(Criteria::expr()->isNull('functions'))
        ->orWhere(Criteria::expr()->isNull('salutation'))
        ->orWhere(Criteria::expr()->isNull('category'))
        ->orWhere(Criteria::expr()->isNull('address'))
        ->orWhere(Criteria::expr()->isNull('city'))
        ->orWhere(Criteria::expr()->isNull('company'));

$contactObj = $this->em->getRepository("ImporterBundle:Contact")
        ->matching($criteria);
```

[Doctrine expression builder](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-collections/en/1.6/expression-builder.html)